# How to override attachments page links in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to change link to attachment page in wordpress for two days. i am close to resign right now...

What i have right now is:

```
mysite.com/?attachment_id=1234
```

What I need is:

```
mysite.com/{postname}/image/{attachment_id}
```

I have found something at stack

```
function __filter_rewrite_rules( $rules )
{
    $_rules = array();
    foreach ( $rules as $rule => $rewrite )
        $_rules[ str_replace( 'attachment', 'media', $rule  ) ] = $rewrite;
    return $_rules;
}
add_filter( 'rewrite_rules_array', '__filter_rewrite_rules' );

function __filter_attachment_link( $link )
{
    return str_replace( 'attachment', 'media', $link );
}
add_filter( 'attachment_link', '__filter_attachment_link' );
```

But actually it do not change anything. I am not able to enter page with attachment using link:

```
mysite.com/media_id=123
```

Please explain me why?

Comment: did you refresh your permalinks?

Comment: If you mean flush rewrite rules - yes I did it

Comment: I know in the past I've had to go to the permalinks page and hit 'save' on them sometimes to get rules to flush out.

Comment: I have done it before without any result..

Comment: Have you tried changing `$_rules[ str_replace( 'attachment', 'media', $rule  ) ]` to just `$_rules[$rule]` ? prehaps the old rule is taking precedence over yours somehow. (These are just shots in the dark for things I would try first before digging into core to figure it out)